# \let and sneaky redefinitions that are wrappers for the original macro: is there a similar thing for environments?

Tags: macros, environments

Let's say I am using some macro `\foo` that almost does what I want, but I actually want to add space either side of the output of `\foo`. I can do the following:

```
\let\tempfoo\foo
\renewcommand\foo{\hspace{1em}\tempfoo\hspace{1em}}
```

This redefines `\foo` to do what it did before, plus some extra space either side. Is there a way to "patch" environments in the same way? I guess the question is really how do I `\let` with environments?

Comment: I was searching for a question like this, but almost missed it because of the slightly verbose title. Would you consider changing it to something like *Is there a \let for environments?*? This would also make it more general – my actual use case is not a sneaky redefinition, but plain aliasing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An environment `foo` defines the two macros `\foo` and `\endfoo`. You can redefine both in the same as you already did:

```
\let\origfoo\foo
\let\endorigfoo\endfoo
\renewenvironment{foo}
    {<your stuff>\origfoo<your stuff>}
    {<your stuff>\endorigfoo<your stuff>}
```

However, using the package `etoolbox` with its macros makes life easier.

Comment: Indeed, like this: `\let\origfooenv\fooenv \let\endorigfooenv\endfooenv \renewenvironment{fooenv}{<your stuff>\origfooenv<your stuff>}{<your stuff>\endorigfooenv<your stuff>}`

Comment: @MartinScharrer I took the liberty of adding your code to the answer; it was kind of hard to read as a comment. I hope that’s ok and feel free to delete both of our comments.

Comment: @doncherry I had to adapt a bit for fitting to question and original answer of Herbert.

Answer (score 7):

The most practical way is to exploit **etoolbox**'s utilities:

```
\preto\foo{\hspace{1em}}
\appto\foo{\hspace{1em}}
```

The problem arises for commands with "apparent arguments", for example `\section`. If you look at the output of `\show\section`, you'll see that it has *no* argument whatsoever. It's a technique frequently employed in LaTeX, because it's more efficient. Actually `\section` is transformed into

```
\@startsection{...}{...}{...}{...}{...}
```

and `\@startsection` has *six* arguments; you see that `\section` supplied the first five, the sixth is what comes after `\section` (there's more to this, because there can be a * or an optional argument, but let's keep it simple).

Using the trick with `\appto` for a command like `\section` would result in a disaster, because the thing added will provide the sixth argument for `\@startsection`, which is clearly not what is wanted.

As Herbert says, you can use `\preto` and `\appto` also for environments, using `\foo` and `\endfoo` if the environment is `foo`, provided the environment has no argument. If the argument is part of the command (i.e. it is not "apparent") one can use `\pretocmd` and `\apptocmd`; if the argument is apparent (it's the case of `\tabular`, for example) `\appto` and `\apptocmd` *must not* be used, but `\preto` and `\pretocmd` are quite safe.

Comment: But the sneaky `\let` thing will work with `\section` won't it? Isn't that a point in favour of using that trick, rather than `etoolbox`?

Comment: @Seamus: Not for things after `\tempsection`.

Comment: Ah right. I see. I only tried with something before it...

Answer (score 7):

For environments, you can use `\AtBeginEnvironment`, `\AtEndEnvironment`, `\BeforeBeginEnvironment`, and `\AfterEndEnvironment` provided by [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox). `etoolbox` add some hooks for environments. You may also use `\appto` and `\preto` to patch `\foo` and `\endfoo`. The two methods work differently.

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newenvironment{foo}{(}{)}

\begin{document}
\begin{foo}foo\end{foo}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{foo}{[}
\AfterEndEnvironment{foo}{]}
\begin{foo}foo\end{foo}

\appto\foo{\{}
\preto\endfoo{\}}
\begin{foo}foo\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another *sneaky* way is to add something at the beginning or the end of macros. LaTeX provides the command `\g@addto@macro` to append to an existing macro, whereas etoolbox provides commands both for `prepending` as well as appending. The following code modifies the `\begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\document}{ Oh! I see!}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\g@addto@macro` is almost the same as `\appto`, with the difference that `\appto` acts locally (its effect will disappear at the end of the group where it's issued), while `\g@addto@macro` acts always *globally*; **etoolbox** has `\gappto` for this.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. I am aware the beauty though of `\g@addto@macro` is that it is built into the LaTeX kernel.

Comment: of course! I use it quite frequently, when **etoolbox** would be overkill.